# Rails; Validate parameters within service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a service object in Rails to encapsulate business logic of creating plans for Stripe(https://stripe.com/).
Is there any good pattern for handling parameter validation for **Service** objects?

For validations:

- I have to check all the inputs for nil or wrong type. Is there any way for easy validation? Maybe a rails extension?

Here is an example;

```
# app/services/service.rb
module Service
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.call(*args)
      new(*args).call
    end
  end
end

# app/services/plan/create.rb
class Plan::Create
  include Service

  attr_reader :params

  def initialize(params = {})
    @params = params.dup
  end

  def call
    plan = Plan.new(attrs)
    return plan unless plan.valid?

    begin
      external_card_plan_service.create(api_attrs)
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      plan.errors[:base] << e.message
      return plan
    end

    plan.save
    plan.update(is_active: true, activated_at: Time.now.utc)
    plan
  end

  private

  def external_card_plan_service
    Stripe::Plan
  end

  def build_data_hash
    {
      id: params.fetch(:stripe_plan_id)
      stripe_plan_id: params.fetch(:stripe_plan_id)
      amount: params.fetch(:amount)
      currency: params.fetch(:currency)
      interval: params.fetch(:interval)
      name: params.fetch(:name)
      description: params.fetch(:description)
    }
  end

  def attrs
    build_data_hash.slice(:stripe_plan_id, :amount, :currency, :interval, :name, :description)
  end

  def api_attrs
    build_data_hash.slice(:id, :amount, :currency, :interval, :name)
  end
end
```

Ref: http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.

**UPDATE**

The example above is not that complicated.
However if the service object is called within service object, It would bee  better to validate parameters. `CreateUser.call(email_address)`

```
class CreateSubscription
  def self.call(plan, email_address, token)
    user, raw_token = CreateUser.call(email_address)

    subscription = Subscription.new(
      plan: plan,
      user: user
    )

    begin
      stripe_sub = nil
      if user.stripe_customer_id.blank?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          source: token,
          email: user.email,
          plan: plan.stripe_id,
        )
        user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
        user.save!
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.first
      else
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_id)
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.create(
          plan: plan.stripe_id
        )
      end

      subscription.stripe_id = stripe_sub.id

      subscription.save!
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    end

    subscription
  end 
end
```

And I tried using Virtus(https://github.com/solnic/virtus).
However I have no clue how to use it within this types of service object.

**UPDATE**

```
# api/v1/controller/plans_controller.rb
    module Api
      module V1
        class PlansController < Api::V1::ApiController
          before_action :check_type, only: [:create]

          def create
            @result = Plan::Create.call(plan_info_params)

            if @result.errors.blank?
              resource = Api::V1::PlanResource.new(@result, nil)

              # NOTE: Include all domains created within this routine.
              serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(Api::V1::PlanResource)
              json_body = serializer.serialize_to_hash(resource)
              render json: json_body, status: 201 # :ok
            else
              errors = jsonapi_errors(@result)
              response = { errors: errors }
              render json: response, status: 422 # :unprocessable_entity
            end
          end

          private

          def check_type
            data_type = 'plans'
            unless params.fetch('data', {}).fetch('type', {}) == data_type
              render json: { errors: [{ title: 'Unprocessable Entity', detail: "Type must be #{data_type}" }] }, status: 422
            end
          end

          def plan_info_params
            params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(:stripe_plan_id, :amount, :currency, :interval, :name, :description)
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dry-validation](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/) is a decent solution.

```
class PlanForm
    include DryValidationForm

    Schema = Dry::Validation.Form do
      required(:stripe_plan_id).filled(:int?)
      required(:stripe_plan_id).filled(:int?)
      required(:amount).filled(:int?, gt?: 0)
      required(:currency).filled(:str?)
      required(:name).filled(:str?)
      optional(:description).maybe(:str?)
    end
  end
end
```

Probably the best place to call form would from controller where you get the params. Then pass valid params to service object

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So here Form object is used right? Also I'm not sure if Form object would be okay because we've been building API.

Comment: @TSH Forms are used for validation and preparation of params for further processing. So yeah, form object is a great choice here, doesn't matter whether it's for API or not.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about virtus + form object?  I'd love to know pros and cons.

Comment: @TSH in out project, we switched from virtus based forms _(there is gem `reform`)_ to `dry-validation`, as it was more convenient. However, I can't remember any particular problems with virtus. There were some cumbersomes, when form became complex _(nested objects, etc)_ . Nothing impossible to solve, though.

Comment: Sounds nice. I've been trying to add it but I've been unable to find any in-app implementation examples. It would be really great if you show me how to implement it within the controller based on the example above. I updated my question!

Comment: I only use strong parameters, and json-api resources for serializing.

Comment: @TSH sure, I'll write an example implementation in a few hours

Comment: Thanks you so much!!

Comment: I've been struggling how to join the dry validation part and example above... I hope you could write the example implementation..

Comment: @TSH Sorry, got a little busy during christmas holidays. I've put up a gist, it should help https://gist.github.com/TheSmartnik/eb883207353c019db94d6cb405eb6f51

Comment: In the answer, I did forget to include  source of `DryValidationForm`. So it's no surprise you've been struggling, really sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Thank you so much! I will try!

Comment: With dry-validation, strong_parameter is not needed. However what about validations living within models?

Comment: @Tosh I believe there is nothing wrong with validation in models if it's not a business logic validation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. I found the validation with scope can be used for business logic such as 'validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :article_id}'. Should I validate it with dry-validation? What do you think?

Comment: @Tosh uniqueness validation in model is fine. One more thing though, I would suggest to add uniq index on those fields, to avoid any race conditions.

Comment: Okay. I got it. One last question, I use service object and each service object has composed like plan/create, plan/update. So each method had different required parameters. In this case, creating PlanCreateForm, PlanUpdateForm for each makes sense?

Comment: Also I tried that. however I got 'NoMethodError - undefined method `Form' for Dry::Validation:Module:' error...

Comment: I explicitly specify gem 'dry-validation', git: 'git://github.com/dry-rb/dry-validation.git', tag: 'v0.10.3' and then it works. maybe the gem on the repo is too old or something else...